# What is bm25 and why elasticsearch chose this algorithm for scoring in version 5 and above

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anybody explain it to me what is bm-25 and how it differs from tf-idf which was previously used and Why Elasticsearch in version 5.0+ changed their scoring algorithm from tf-idf to bm25.

Comment: See [this](https://speakerdeck.com/elastic/improved-text-scoring-with-bm25) talk.

Answer (score 2):

[BM-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) is ranking function which calculates score to represent a document's relevance with respect to query. In tests this approach gives better results compared to earlier [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) based scoring.

Lucene switched to BM-25 as default scoring from 6.0 - which is underlying search library used by Elasticsearch and SOLR

Comment: In addition, here is an interesting article that explains the difference: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/